# how to set a UILabel with data from parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying set a label with an object from parse.com. I'm coding in swift and can't seem to find any information on how to grab a string from an object on parse to display in a label.

Comment: You can't figure out how to get data out of the objects Parse gives you *and* you can't find *any* documentation?  Really?  Seriously?  How did you even manage to get an object from Parse at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Countries")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock{

        (namelist: [AnyObject]!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

        for list in namelist{

            var output = list["nameEnglish"] as String
            self.finalValue.text = output

            println(output)
        }



    }
```

Output:
India
USA
China

and Output on my iOS simulator is China. Hope this solves your problem.